# Opencart - Access document class in every where

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-3

I stored some data in "catalog/controller/product.php" OC v2.0.3.1 by using

> $this->document->setSomeData("data");

I need to read the data in "system/library/response.php" by using

> $this->document->getSomeData

But the document class is not reachable there. what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass $registry into response class in your system/framework.php like this:

```
$response = new Response($registry);
```

In your response class add:

```
private $registry;
public function __construct($registry){
    $this->registry = $registry;
}
```

use:

```
$document = $this->registry->get('document');
$document->setSomeData("data");
```